# How to filter sql duplicates?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

My question: I want the records without duplicate, in the same table and in multiple tables? How can I proceed to do this in SQL?

Let me explain what I have tried:

```
Select distinct Col1, col2
from Table
where order id = 143
```

**Output**

```
VolumeAnswer1    AreaAnswer1    heightAnswer1
VolumeAnswer2    AreaAnswer1    heightAnswer2
VolumeAnswer3    AreaAnswer1    heightAnswer2
```

**Expected Output**
It shows the duplicate for the second table, but I need the output to be like:

```
VolumeAnswer1    AreaAnswer1    heightAnswer1
VolumeAnswer2                   heightAnswer2
VolumeAnswer3
```

I need the same scenario for multiple tables, same duplicate I found for joins also. If it cannot be handled in SQL Server, how can we handle it in .Net? I used multiple select but they used to change it in single select. Each and every column should bind in dropdownlist...

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you please explain what you mean by the duplicate records in multiple tables (maybe by editing you question)? And can you add the column names to your output/expected output? Thanks :-)

Comment: A test case with complete test data and sql syntax would be nice.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this might be a good place to start:

```
;with cte1 as (
Select col1, cnt1
From (
  Select
    col1
    ,row_number() over(Partition by col1 Order by col1) as cnt1
  From tbltest) as tbl_sub1
Where cnt1 = 1
), cte2 as (
Select col2, cnt2
From (
  Select
    col2
    ,row_number() over(Partition by col2 Order by col2) as cnt2
  From tbltest) as tbl_sub2
Where cnt2 = 1
), cte3 as (
Select col3, cnt3
From (
  Select
    col3
    ,row_number() over(Partition by col3 Order by col3) as cnt3
  From tbltest) as tbl_sub3
Where cnt3 = 1
)
Select
col1, col2, col3
From cte1
full join cte2 on col1 = col2
full join cte3 on col1 = col3
```

Sql Fiddle showing example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c9127/1

Comment: Thank you very much, You did fentastic job.. i love u lot